# grep only-matching not working as expected

Tags: bash, grep

I was trying to do a very simple grep --only-matching on 'height=xxx', and the result is quite strange as showed on the screenshot.

Does someone know what is it about ?

[image]

GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?cb=1)

Comment: I feel this is not enough information.  Can you give us a dataset to test against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably through some alias, your system forces `grep` output to be in color.  Don't do that.

On my system, the code produces the correct output:

```
$ echo "$value" | grep -Eo 'height=[0-9]+' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'
532
```

If, however, I force color, then I see the output you see:

```
$ echo "$value" | grep -Eo --color=always 'height=[0-9]+' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'
01
31
532
```

Don't force color.  It is common, for one or more of the bash initialization files to set aliases to make interactive use of commands more pleasant.  In your alias, replace `--color=always` with `--color=auto`.